# Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm starting to learn react native and I am following this tutorial on fullstackreact :

https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/react-tutorial-cloning-yelp/#_really_-quickstart

When I run `NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/hjs-dev-server`, I get the following error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
at found (/Users/kyle/yelp/webpack.config.js:69:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kyle/yelp/webpack.config.js:74:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kyle/yelp/node_modules/hjs-
webpack/bin/hjs-dev-server.js:17:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
Failed to load webpack config, please use like this
hjs-dev-server.js webpack.config.js
```

My `webpack.config.js` file is a direct copy and paste from here:
https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-yelp-clone/blob/master/webpack.config.js

The line in question looks like :

```
const findLoader = (loaders, match) => {
const found = loaders.filter(l => l && l.loader && 
l.loader.match(match))
return found ? found[0] : null;
}
```

I did not seem to encounter any errros while following this tutorial, if anyone could give me some help as to how to resolve this error I would be very appreciative.

Thanks

Comment: loaders is undefined. Did you make sure config.module.loaders is set correctly when you are passing into findLoader?